# How to insert carriage returns in ribbon button labels in Office Add-ins XML manifest?

Tags: xml, office-addins

In my `manifest.xml,` I have a button's label defined like this:

```
 <bt:String id="PG.conectar_online_DR.Label" DefaultValue="Conectar Online Data Report" />
```

However, this splits like this:

```
Conectar Online Data 
Report
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Conectar Online 
Data Report
```

So, I try to insert a carriage return in the label like so:

<bt:String id="PG.conectar_online_DR.Label" DefaultValue="Conectar Online&#13;Data Report" />

or

<bt:String id="PG.conectar_online_DR.Label" DefaultValue="Conectar Online\nData Report" />

Both give me **invalid manifest** errors when trying to load them.
Is there another way to do this?